# Process of generating file getting slow overtime

Tags: java

So we built a process that generate a batch of voucher codes + some informations about each code and write all of this to a CSV file in order to integrate through SFTP.

The process is dynamic, meaning that it receive quantity it have to generate through a configuration file. Now, the process is trying to generate 55000 codes. This implies in a file with 55000 lines ending up with only ~8.5MB (not a large file at all).

The problem is that the process is getting really slow overtime. The logic used to build was the following:

> 1 - Read the configuration file to find out the quantity to be
> generated and to find out for which partner the file is.
>
> 2 - Query the database to get some configurations of that specific
> partner
>
> 3 - If the quantity is greater than 5k, split the process in multiple
> loops in order to have the GC being able to collect some objects and
> free some memory

This is the basic logic, but there are a lot more going on:

> 1 - We are using `FileWriter` to write to the file (we've tested it
> out and the `write` operations are happening fast, as well as the
> `flush` operations, apparently, atleast).
>
> 2 - At each of the 55000 operations, we have to trigger the database 2
> times, one to know if the generated code already exists + one to
> insert the generated code.
>
> 3 - When the process is greater than 5k, we divide into loops, so lets
> say that the batch is of 12k. We split in 3 loops. 2 of 5k + 1 of 2k.
> This is because we have limited memory so we want the garbage
> collector to be able to free some memory at each 5k iteration (I know
> it's hard to know when GC will run, but by doing that we make sure
> that the objects have no reference)

A demonstration of the code:

```
quantity = readConfigFile();
partnetConfigs = getPartnerSpecificConfigsFromDB();
writer = new FileWriter(...);
if (quantity > 5000) {
    remaining = quantity
    while (remaining > 0) {
        currentBatchSize = remaining - 5000 < 0 ? remaining : 5000;
        vouchers = generate(partnerConfigs, currentBatchSize); // this method trigger the database 2 * currentBatchSize
        appendToFile(writer, vouchers);
        writer.flush(); // flushes the stream at the end of each 5000 to release any data from the buffer
        remaining -= currentBatchSize;
    }
} else {
    vouchers = generate(partnerConfigs, quantity); // this method trigger the database 2 * quantity
    appendToFile(writer, vouchers);
}

writer.close();

...
```

The process is getting slow overtime. When generating 50.000 of codes, the following happens:

```
1st 5.000 took 8 minutes
2nd 5.000 took 23 minutes
3rd 5.000 took 37 minutes
4th 5.000 took 50 minutes
5th 5.000 took 1 hour and 10 minutes
6th 5.000 took 1 hour and 24 minutes
7th 5.000 took 2 hours
```

Why is this happening?

### UPDATE

As suggested by Petr in the comments I used a profiler to see what was going on with my application. I could not attach the profiler to the existing process in the remote JVM, but I tested it out in another server, with the same data, even the same database instance - I used JProfiler.

The results I got was somehow expected.

> 1 - The db operations were fast (7ms ~ 10ms per statement executed)
>
> 2 - The write operations were fast (1ms ~ 3ms to append each 5k batch)
>
> 3 - This server generated 55000 vouchers in a matter of 22 minutes.

I'm supposing that there is something wrong with the other server. We are waiting for the infrastructure team to analyze what is going on more in depth and see why the performance is so poor.

Comment: Did you check the time taken by the database to return?

Comment: @srdg yes! it actually returns pretty quickly..

Comment: Interesting. I would suggest playing around with the batch size a bit, in case you haven't already. I'm curious to see what might the reason be, but I have a gut feeling telling me the memory access time is causing the bottleneck.

Comment: You'll have the most luck by looking at what your application is spending the time on. Try profiling, nowadays any profiler will, do though I recommend https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler for sure. If you can't do that, at least take a few thread dumps via [`jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jcmd.html). I'm sure you'll see what's going on pretty quickly.

Comment: Have you tested the time taken by insert operations for a very last loop iteration? For example, each query might go slower and slower, when DB rearranges indexed columns. So if you test it with an empty database, it will show you much better performance than it is going to be

Comment: Is `generate()` re-utilizing the same DB connection across calls?...or is it creating a new connection for each batch?  Without seeing `generate()` or `appendToFile()`, this is nearly impossible to troubleshoot from our end.

Comment: @Idle_Mind it is reusing the same connection across all db calls. Im profiling as suggested by Petr and I'll update with the results asap. So far I'm guessing that the problem is on the machine that is running the process, but unfortunately, I can't attach a profiler to there, so I'm testing it in another machine to atleast see the time taken by the queries.